# "Learn Lab" or "Learning Lab"?

Tags: word-choice

I work at a community college where we have help centers to accommodate our students in various disciplines (math, writing, etc.).  One of the requirements
for us faculty is that we must verify that students who seek help are indeed "allowed/eligible" to receive said help (a ridiculous administrative process IMHO).  Anyhow, the powers that be have called it the "Learn Lab Referral."

It seems to me it should be called the "Learning Lab Referral."  However, each time I have made my suggestion, I was told that "Learn" is correct and
and "Learning" is not.

Who is correct?  If it is me, and it should be "Learning," then I would greatly appreciate an explanation so convincing that even an administrator could not deny!  :-)

Thank you in advance for sharing your knowledge in this area (my area of expertise is mathematics, not English).

Abe Mantell

Comment: Clearly you are teaching in a school where the administrators are not native speakers of English (although you didn't say so). *_Learn Lab_ is a novel and non-standard construction; in the United States, the usual fixed phrase for an academic facility of this sort is exactly _Learning Lab_. Verbs used to modify nouns normally are participles, not infinitives; there are thousands of examples -- _shooting gallery,_ not *_shoot gallery;_ _writing desk,_ not *_write desk,_ and so on.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's true, but not universal, e.g. *computer class* and *math class* rather than *computing class* and *calculating class*. However, another difficulty with this is that proper names of organizations and departments don't always follow grammatical rules -- If you want to name a learning lab "The Learn Lab", you can get away with it.

Comment: This is more likely to be done in contexts where cute names and wordplay are appropriate, like businesses. One might name a commercial tutoring service "Learn Unit", as a play on "Burn Unit" in hospitals.

Comment: @Barmar: _Computer class_ and _math class_ is a noun compound, because all parts are nouns. Neither _computer_ nor _math_ is a verb, hence neither one can be an infinitive or a participle. And proper names are always exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

[Check out this Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learning+lab%2C+learn+lab&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clearning%20lab%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clearn%20lab%3B%2Cc0) to see the relative frequency of "Learning Lab" and "Learn Lab" in English language books. Clearly, usage is on your side.

Further, to quote John Lawler, one of our most learned and esteemed participants:

> *Learn Lab is a novel and non-standard construction; in the United States, the usual fixed phrase for an academic facility of this sort is exactly Learning Lab. Verbs used to modify nouns normally are participles, not infinitives; there are thousands of examples -- shooting gallery, not *shoot gallery; writing desk, not *write desk, and so on.